# Unable to determine the principal end of the relationship ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm currently building an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with EF 6.1.3 linked to an SQL Server database.

My issue: I receive the following error when I attempt to save 2 or more instantiations of "PurchaseInvoiceSplitsViewModel", no issue when only 1 saved.

> **Unable to determine the principal end of the 'WebAS.Models.PurchaseInvoiceSplits_VehicleStock' relationship.
>   Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.**

The issue arises at line `_context.SaveChanges();`

My ViewModel:

```
public class PurchaseInvoiceHeaderFormViewModel
{
    public PurchaseInvoiceHeaderFormViewModel()
    { 
        Splits = new List<PurchaseInvoiceSplitsViewModel>();  
    }      
    public List<PurchaseInvoiceSplitsViewModel> Splits  { get; set; }     
}

public class PurchaseInvoiceSplitsViewModel
{
    public PurchaseInvoiceSplits PurchaseInvoiceSplits { get; set; }
    public VehicleInformation VehicleInformation { get; set; }  
    public VehicleStock VehicleStock { get; set; }
}
```

My Models:

```
 public class VehicleStock
 {   
    [Key]     
    public int VehicleStockId { get; set; }       
    public int VehicleInformationId { get; set; }
    public VehicleInformation VehicleInformation { get; set; }
 }

  public class PurchaseInvoiceSplits
  {
    [Key]       
    public int PurchaseInvoiceSplitsId { get; set; }
    public int? VehicleStockId { get; set; }
    public VehicleStock VehicleStock { get; set; }
  }

  public class VehicleInformation
  {
    [Key]
    public int VehicleInformationId { get; set; }
  }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult Save(PurchaseInvoiceHeaderFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
      _context.PurchaseInvoiceHeader.Add(viewModel.PurchaseInvoiceHeader); 

      foreach (var Split in viewModel.Splits)
       {          
        Split.PurchaseInvoiceSplits.VehicleStockId =                                               
                                                    Split.VehicleStock.Id;
        Split.VehicleStock.VehicleInformationId = 
                                              Split.VehicleInformation.Id;                   

       _context.VehicleInformation.Add(Split.VehicleInformation);
       _context.VehicleStock.Add(Split.VehicleStock);        
       _context.PurchaseInvoiceSplits.Add(Split.PurchaseInvoiceSplits);
       }

      _context.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("xxx", "xxx");            
    }
```

I have spent ages looking into this and I believe it is related to EF assigning temporary Id's of 0 to the models. This is fine when there is one model but appears to cause navigation/reference issues with multiple model instantiations. Answers to other forum posts suggest using temporary Id's which I have attempted but have not managed to get to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please feel free to ask for further clarification/code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved using Entity Framework Transactions (note, only appear to be available for version 6+). Very useful information found here:

[Entity Framework Tutorials](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/transaction-in-entity-%20framework.aspx)

[MSDN turotials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx)

Modifications only required within Controller:

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult Save(PurchaseInvoiceHeaderFormViewModel viewModel)
{
 using (CustData Tcontext = new CustData())
 {
   using (DbContextTransaction transaction = 
                                       Tcontext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    { 
    try
    {
      Tcontext.PurchaseInvoiceHeader.Add(viewModel.PurchaseInvoiceHeader);
      Tcontext.SaveChanges();

      foreach (var Split in viewModel.Splits)
      {                                
        Tcontext.VehicleInformation.Add(Split.VehicleInformation);                                

        Split.VehicleStock.VehicleInformationId = Split.VehicleInformation.Id;            

        Tcontext.VehicleStock.Add(Split.VehicleStock);                                

        Split.PurchaseInvoiceSplits.VehicleStockId = Split.VehicleStock.Id;                                

        Split.PurchaseInvoiceSplits.PurchaseInvoiceNumberId = viewModel.PurchaseInvoiceHeader.Id;

        Tcontext.PurchaseInvoiceSplits.Add(Split.PurchaseInvoiceSplits);
        Tcontext.SaveChanges();
      }

     transaction.Commit();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Error occurred." + ex);                       
   }
  }
 }
return RedirectToAction("xxx", "xxx");            
}
```

I believe that the order in which the .Add occurs is also important, hence the rearrange.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and an unsimilar code setup, but...

I took a look at the above answer and noticed the comment at the bottom: **I believe that the order in which the .Add occurs is also important, hence the rearrange.**

What I did was arrange the saves in my code and was able to eliminate the error. I just thought I would post this for future error searches.